# Populating a list that contains an array using linq

Tags: c#, json, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5, vis.js

I am using visjs.net to display a schedule

I'm having trouble writing LINQ to populate a list that contains a property that is an array

Here is the visjs documentation [visjs doco](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#groups)

and some example code [visjs source code](http://view-source:http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/groups/nestedGroups.html)

Here is an abridged version of the sample in javascript. I need to populate this JSON from a MVC controller instead of javascript

```
  var groups = new vis.DataSet();

  groups.add([
    {
      id: 1,
      content: "Lee",
      nestedGroups: [11,12]
    }
  ]);

  groups.add([
    {
      id: 11,
      content: "cook",
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      content: "shop",
    }
  ]);
```

spoiler alert: I don't know how to populate the nestedGroups property

This is the class I built for it:

```
    public class TimelineGroups
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string content { get; set; }
        public string className { get; set; }
        public string orderBy { get; set; }
        public string[] nestedGroups { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the controller method that populates it, excluding the nestedGroups property, and this works just fine:

```
    public JsonResult EmployeeGroups()
    {
        List<TimelineGroups> e = (
            from emp in db.Employees
            where emp.Emp_Status == 1 && emp.EmployeeRole.IsChargeable == "Y"
            orderby emp.EmpRole_ID, emp.Emp_Last_Name
            select new TimelineGroups()
            {
                id = emp.Emp_ID,
                content = emp.Emp_Name,
                orderBy = emp.EmpRole_ID.ToString(),
                className = "bte-" + emp.EmployeeRole.EmpRoleName
            }
            ).ToList();

        return Json(e, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This all works correctly but now I want to add nested groups.

But I don't know the LINQ required to 'pivot' the required data into an array inside a collection.

This is what I have so far:

```
public JsonResult EmployeeClientGroups()
{
    // First load the client list which are children of employees
    List<TimelineGroups> cg = (
        from sw in db.ScheduleWorks
        where sw.EndDate > DateTime.Now
        select new TimelineGroups()
        {
            id = sw.Employee.Emp_ID * 1000 + sw.CustomerId,
            content = sw.Customer.Customer_Name
        }).Take(1000).Distinct().ToList();

    // now load the employee list
    // This includes client children
    List<TimelineGroups> eg = (
        from sw in db.ScheduleWorks
        where sw.EndDate > DateTime.Now
        select new TimelineGroups()
        {
            id = sw.Employee.Emp_ID,
            // How do I populate this with sw.Employee.Emp_ID * 1000 + sw.CustomerId
            nestedGroups = // What magic do I put here?
            content = sw.Employee.Emp_Name,
        }).Take(1000).Distinct().ToList();

    // Add the employee groups to the client groups
    cg.AddRange(eg);

    return Json(cg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

I need to get all the client ID's for a given Employee and "pivot" them into an array, suitable to post back as JSON

To make them unique and match the children id's, the value I need to pivot in is:

`sw.Employee.Emp_ID * 1000 + sw.CustomerId`

Can this be done inline in a LINQ statement?

Comment: AFAIK you can perform addition in a LINQ `select`, but in this case you're trying to insert `int` value to a `string[]` array which is certainly an invalid cast. Check this simplified fiddle and let me know if declaring `new string[]` to `nestedGroups` is what you want to do: https://dotnetfiddle.net/40lDp9.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to set up a fiddle. I'll try this solution tonight. I hope it really is that easy!

Comment: For the sample data that you kindly prepared, I should see one member of the list, with Id= 1234, and nestedGroups = (array of 1,2,3,4,5,6). I'll get back to you after I try it out

Comment: I think this is my answer here but I'm struggling to understand the syntax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, again thanks for taking the time to build the fiddle for me. I hope you don't mind, I have taken your fiddle a bit further and documented my result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out this was kind of answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq) but I will document my solution

This is the code that I eventually used:

```
    public class TimelineGroups
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string content { get; set; }
        public string className { get; set; }
        public string orderBy { get; set; }
        public List<string> nestedGroups { get; set; }
    }


        List<TimelineGroups> eg = (
            from sw in db.ScheduleWorks
            where sw.EndDate > DateTime.Now
            where sw.Employee.Emp_Status == 1

            group (sw.EmployeeId.ToString() + "." + sw.CustomerId.ToString())
            by new {
                id = sw.EmployeeId.ToString(),
                EmpName = sw.Employee.Emp_Name,
                EmpOrder = sw.Employee.EmpRole_ID.ToString()
            }

            into g

            select new TimelineGroups()
            {
                id = g.Key.id,
                // find the list of employee+client keys 
                nestedGroups = g.ToList(),
                content = g.Key.EmpName,
                orderBy = g.Key.EmpOrder
            })
            .Take(1000)
            .ToList();
```

- Note no `Distinct`
- The argument to `group` is the field holding the values that i want to "pivot"
- then the part after `by` is the actual 'key' that will be grouped on
- I needed to use a `List()` rather than an array (maybe I could've used `ToArray` though?)
- Once this is grouped into an intermediate variable `g`, you can use `g.ToList()` to get the 'pivoted' values

Hopefully this will help someone else one day, maybe even someone using the visjs library

@Tetsuya Yamamoto fiddle pointed me in the right direction